# Datanode Dies After a Few Seconds

Tags: hadoop

I am running Apache Hadoop version 1.0.4.

I followed a tutorial here: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/ with some tweaks to set up Hadoop.

The data node starts when I use the script start-dfs.sh but dies after some time (less then a second).

```
hduser@mudit-Studio-1535:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ jps
25672 NameNode
26276 SecondaryNameNode
25970 DataNode
26328 Jps

hduser@mudit-Studio-1535:/usr/local/hadoop/bin$ jps
25672 NameNode
26276 SecondaryNameNode
26360 Jps
```

Similar problem is encountered when I use start-all.sh

I tried formatting the namenode by `./hadoop namenode -format`. The output is

Still I am getting the same problem.

Comment: can you show me your datanode logs?and what are those tweaks?

Comment: check in the processes if datanode is already running by some other user and try to kill that process..
ps aux | grep Datanode

Comment: Submit the tail of your datanode logs please (there will most probably be an exception trace - that's what we'll need to assist you)